# Can't decrypt string with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to encode/decode data using CryptoJS, as a preliminar test for the code I want to develop. This is the code I'm using for encrypting:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
var message = "Secret Message";
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('36ebe205bcdfc499a25e6923f4450fa8');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('be410fea41df7162a679875ec131cf2c');

// Encription. Works ok
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        message,key,
        {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }
    );
console.log('encrypted:'+encrypted.ciphertext.toString());
<script>
```

This is the first test I use for decrypting. It works OK, returning `3f0e590d2617dc7007b89350bd590409`

```
// Decription. Works ok with "encrypted" parameter
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        encrypted,key,
        {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }
    );
console.log('decrypted:'+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Let's notice that `encrypted` parameter is the results from the previous call to `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`. It's an object.

The problem I have is when I try to decrypt directly the string:

```
// Decription. It fails with manual data
var manual_data = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('3f0e590d2617dc7007b89350bd590409');
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        manual_data,key,
        {
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }
    );
console.log('decrypted, by hand:'+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

It returns an "empty" object (an empty string in the above example). It seems like there is some data that CryptoJS.AES.decrypt needs which is stored into the encrypted object of the first example but missing from the wordarray of the second example.

Does anybody knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have been messing with this a while and I think I have found your problem. The main problem is this line `encrypted.ciphertext.toString()`. What you want is just `encrypted.toString()`.

The `toString` function is defined for this object by CryptoJS and it returns the encrypted message that can be sent around safely. So if we change that we will have something like this:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  message,
  key,
  {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }
);
console.log('            encrypted: '+encrypted.toString());
```

This will output `Pw5ZDSYX3HAHuJNQvVkECQ==` instead of `3f0e590d2617dc7007b89350bd590409`. The reason your second function is working is because it doesn't use `encrypted.ciphertext.toString()` it just uses the actual object so no changes on that one. For the last one we will have the change the wrong text you were using to the new text that is returned without the `ciphertext` part but we also have to remove the `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse`. I don't really know what you were doing here but I can investigate if you meant something by that.

```
var manual_data = 'Pw5ZDSYX3HAHuJNQvVkECQ==';
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  manual_data,
  key,
  {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }
);
console.log('   decrypted, by hand: '+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

This should log the right stuff.

I have even created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oHEKIZEB/1/) for this. It is my first time using JSBin so I hope I did it right.

Comment: JSBin was quickie... It did the job.

Comment: what if I actually need to use the ".ciphertext." part because of remote part I'm talking to only sends the hex-encoded string?
I've been struggling with this for a week and I could not find a way to rebuild the WordArray starting from the ciphertext.

Comment: according to the documentation in the typescript the default value is the hex encoding, when you call encrypted.ciphertext.toString() it returns it as a hex string, and you need to call CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse() to convert it to a CryptoJS.lib.WordArray and then call CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify() on the new word array before you can pass it into the CryptoJS.AES.decrypt otherwise, you'll end up with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

If you still prefer to use the **ciphertext**, by default the when no encoding is passed into the `ciphertext.toString()`, it'll return a `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify` on the ciphertext `WordArray`.

Since **decrypt** takes in text as a **base64** string, you will need to call the following on your **ciphertext** **hex** string before you pass it back into **decrypt**.

`CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encrypted.ciphertext.toString()))`

so in the case,

```
var manual_data = '3f0e590d2617dc7007b89350bd590409';
var base64_data = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(manual_data))
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  base64_data,
  key,
  {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }
);
console.log('decrypted by hand: '+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```