# CryptoJS decrypting (AES) a file bytearray coming from Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am encrypting a file in Java and need to decrypt it at client side.
This is the **server side** code:

```
Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("mysecretmysecret".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(read(sampleFile));
return outputBytes;
```

At client side I use Ajax request to fetch the file and use CryptoJS AES:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'file', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var encryptedData = this.response;
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, "mysecretmysecret");
        console.log(decrypted);
};
xhr.send();
```

But this does not decrypt the file. I get this printed as value of decrypted in the console:

```
W…y.init {words: Array[0], sigBytes: 0}
```

I have also tried converting arraybuffer to WordArray suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567468/how-to-decrypt-an-arraybuffer) but still the same result.
I would be more than glad if someone could point me in the right direction and tell me what I did wrong.

**Edit 1:**
I have solved the issue. The code I used is posted as an answer.

Comment: "mysecretmysecret" is probably not that secret if its sitting there in the client source code.

Comment: @AlexK. This is just a POC. Not yet into real code.

Comment: Do not use strings as keys, use byte arrays.  The conversion from a string to a byte array is ambiguous (BoM at the start? \0 terminator? etc.)  Especially when transferring encrypted data between systems do **not** rely on system defaults.  Explicitly set mode, IV/Nonce etc.  You are doing little of this and are relying on defaults to be the same across systems.  Any mismatched defaults will cause problems.

Comment: @rossum using byte arrays in CryptoJS (and Angular 6, at least) is a nightmare. Do you have a working sample?

Comment: @afe I can't help much since I don't use CryptoJS or Angular.  Perhaps ask on a group specifically for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recap, in Java you're using

- AES,
- ECB (not specified but most often the default; **it's insecure!**),
- PKCS#7 padding (not specified but most often the default; it's the same as PKCS#5 padding), and
- a password of 16 characters as a key of 16 bytes (depending on the default system encoding).

If the key is passed as a string to CryptoJS, it will have to derive the key from the assumed password using OpenSSL's `EVP_BytesToKey` with a single round of MD5. Since your ciphertext is not encoded in an OpenSSL-compatible format, it will fail. The thing is, you don't need that.

The following code would decrypt the ciphertext that is coming from Java correctly, but it's not very secure:

```
var passwordWords = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("mysecretmysecret");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(encryptedData) // or use some encoding
}, passwordWords, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB
});
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // in case the plaintext is text
```

The ECB mode is not included in the basic rollup, so you will have to include that [JavaScript file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/mode-ecb.js) in your page after the main CryptoJS file.
Also, CryptoJS doesn't handle an ArrayBuffer by default. You need to include the [shim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/lib-typedarrays.js) for that (source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611179/1816580)).

---

The problem with this is its insecurity. ECB mode is very insecure.

- **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). The IV/nonce is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. A common way is to put it in front of the ciphertext.
- It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.
- Keys can be derived from passwords, but a proper scheme such as PBKDF2 should be used. Java and CryptoJS both support these.

Comment: thanks @Artjom . This is just a POC and i need to solve this using least possible code. Of course I know ECB is least secure but again, I will look into the hardening later.

Answer (score 2):

So I have finally solved this. Thanks to Artjom for pointing in the right direction.
I have changed my Java code to use CBC with PKCS5Padding .

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec("mysecretmysecret".getBytes(), "AES");
IvParameterSpec IVKey = new IvParameterSpec("mysecretmysecret".getBytes());
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, IVKey);
byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(read(sampleFile));
return outputBytes;
```

And my javascript goes like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'file', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var encryptedData = this.response;
    var passwordWords = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("mysecretmysecret"); //yes I know, not a big secret!
    var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(encryptedData);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
        ciphertext: wordArray
    }, passwordWords, {
        iv: passwordWords, //yes I used password as iv too. Dont mind.
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    console.log(decrypted); //Eureka!!
};

xhr.send();
```

The `decrypted` is a WordArray.

Comment: love this as a starting point. "arraybuffer" matching "wordArray" saved the day. decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8) can show the original text.