# MD5 checksum not calculated properly for files other than txt?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, md5, cryptojs, md5-file

I am using **crypto-js** to calculated the **MD5 checksum** for my file before uploading, below is my code.

```
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

const getMd5 = async (fileObject) => {
  let md5 = "";
  try {
    const fileObjectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(fileObject);
    const blobText = await fetch(fileObjectUrl)
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then((res) => new Response(res).text());

    const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(blobText));
    md5 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error occured getMd5:", err);
  }
  return md5;
};
```

Above code is working fine for **text files** only but while working with **non text files** file **images, videos etc.**, the checksum is calculated incorrectly.

Any help/input is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: [`Response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) goes along with a UTF8 encoding. This corrupts (arbitrary) binary data. Probably [`Response.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer) is the better choice and the data will not be corrupted. However, the `arrayBuffer` still needs to be converted for CryptoJS, since CryptoJS only works with `WordArray`s (probably something like `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create()`, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611179/9014097)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) reads the response stream and converts it to a string using a UTF-8 encoding. Arbitrary binary data that is not UTF-8 compliant will be corrupted in this process (e.g. images, videos, etc.), s. also the other answer.
This is prevented by using [`Response.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer) instead, which simply stores the data unchanged in an `ArrayBuffer`.
Since CryptoJS works internally with `WordArray`s, thus a further conversion of the `ArrayBuffer` into a [`WordArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611179/9014097) is necessary.

The following fix works on my machine:

```js
(async () => {
            
    const getMd5 = async(fileObject) => {
        let md5 = "";
        try {
            const fileObjectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const blobText = await fetch(fileObjectUrl)
                .then((res) => res.blob())
                .then((res) => new Response(res).arrayBuffer());                    // Convert to ArrayBuffer       
            const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(blobText)); // Import as WordArray
            md5 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error occured getMd5:", err);
        }
        return md5;
    };
        
    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x81, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff])]);
    console.log(await(getMd5(blob)));
        
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

For simplicity, I did not use a file object for the test, but a blob object with data that is not UTF8 compliant.
The generated hash is correct and can be verified online e.g. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Auto%27)MD5()&input=MDEwMjAzN2Y4MDgxZmRmZWZm)

Answer (score 2):

Just feed the result of `.then((res) => res.blob())` into the `MD5` function directly.

Encoding to `text()` is probably lossy (and/or uses replacement characters), and `Latin1` doesn't cover the full range of possible byte values either - officially at least. There is just no need to convert to text and then back to binary either.

It is required to convert to a binary representation that can be accepted by CryptoJS - as implemented [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68304001/589259). This however needs to be a binary to binary conversion, not a binary -> text -> binary conversion.